# bootstrap importing only grid bug?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Currently I am importing only bootstrap-grid in my scss file `@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss"` The grid is mostly working, but for small screens the container overflows even with 1px of content.

I saw in tools that there is a -42px margin-right. First I though that thats the problem but it is not.

I then imported whole bootstrap to my scss and the overflow was gone. Then I looked at the values of the container and noticed that the problem was that `box-sizing: border-box;` was missing. After adding it, it works as expected. But my question is, is this a bug, or did I miss to import something that I might want to import, because there can be other problems?

Comment: maybe importing the root module would be a good idea https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/reboot/#page-defaults ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need

```
_variables.scss
_mixins.scss
_normalize.scss
_reboot.scss
_grid.scss
```

to get the grid working.